# SQL Merging 2 tables by closest time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table gps with location and time information (time, lat, long).
I have a table events which keeps the time of certain type of events (time).

I need the sql (mysql preferably) to create a new table: `events_with_gps` that for each record in table events, registers the position (lat, long) of the register of table `gps` that is closer in time for the event.

Example:

```
gps:
11:00:00, 10, 10
11:05:00, 14, 14
11:10:00, 18, 18
11:15:00, 20, 20
11:20:00, 22, 22

events:
11:06:02
11:14:09

events_with_gps:
11:06:02, 14, 14
11:14:09, 20, 20
```

And also, would it be possible to set the location in `events_with_gps` as the average between the previous and next gps register?

```
events_with_gps_avg:
11:06:02, 16, 16
11:14:09, 19, 19
```

Comment: Are `gps` and `events` tables inserted synchronously? if gps was always inserted before events or visa versa, this problem can be solved with sql, otherwise i think you need to script it.

Comment: Both tables exist and are complete already.

Comment: IMHO there is nothing unclear about the question. The OP wants to join `gps` and `events` tables on `time` field *proximity*. The post currently marked as answer provides one way of doing so. Perhaps there is a more elegant and efficient way of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to perform a join on closest time is first to use a `CROSS JOIN` in order to calculate all possible differences between time columns in `gps` and `event` table.

The following query:

```
SELECT e.`time` AS etime, g.`time` AS gtime, g.lat, g.`long`, 
       ABS(TIMEDIFF(e.`time`, g.`time`)) AS diff
FROM events AS e
CROSS JOIN gps AS g
ORDER BY e.`time`, diff
```

produces the following output:

```
etime       gtime       lat long    diff
------------------------------------------
11:06:02    11:05:00    14  14      102
11:06:02    11:10:00    18  18      358
11:06:02    11:00:00    10  10      602
11:06:02    11:15:00    20  20      858
11:06:02    11:20:00    22  22      1358
11:14:09    11:15:00    20  20      51
11:14:09    11:10:00    18  18      409
11:14:09    11:20:00    22  22      551
11:14:09    11:05:00    14  14      909
11:14:09    11:00:00    10  10      1409
```

If you `GROUP BY` etime and use `GROUP_CONCAT` you can select the record having the smallest `diff` value out of the above result set. You can the `JOIN` these records back to `gps` to get the records to be inserted into `events_with_gps`:

```
SELECT t.`time`, g.lat, g.`long`
FROM (
SELECT e.`time`, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          GROUP_CONCAT(g.`time` 
                       ORDER BY ABS(TIMEDIFF(e.`time`, g.`time`))), ',', 1) AS matchedTime
FROM events AS e
CROSS JOIN gps AS g
GROUP BY e.`time` ) t
INNER JOIN gps AS g ON CAST(t.matchedTime AS TIME) = g.`time`
```

**Output:**

```
 time       lat long
-----------------------
'11:06:02'  14  14
'11:14:09'  20  20
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcfdd/1)

To get the second result set you can use the following query to get previous and next `gps` records for each `events` record:

```
SELECT e.`time` as etime, 
       (SELECT `time`
        FROM gps AS g
        WHERE g.`time` <= e.`time`
        ORDER BY g.`time` DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS prevTime,
       (SELECT `time`
        FROM gps AS g
        WHERE g.`time` > e.`time`
        ORDER BY g.`time`  
        LIMIT 1) AS nextTime        
FROM events AS e
```

**Output:**

```
etime     prevTime  nextTime
------------------------------
11:06:02  11:05:00  11:10:00
11:14:09  11:10:00  11:15:00
```

You can now use the above as a *derived table* in order to join back to `gps` and get 'previous' and 'next' `lat` and `long` values:

```
SELECT t.etime, (g1.lat + g2.lat) /2 , (g1.`long` + g2.`long`) / 2
FROM (
SELECT e.`time` as etime, 
       (SELECT `time`
        FROM gps AS g
        WHERE g.`time` <= e.`time`
        ORDER BY g.`time` DESC 
        LIMIT 1) AS prevTime,
       (SELECT `time`
        FROM gps AS g
        WHERE g.`time` > e.`time`
        ORDER BY g.`time`  
        LIMIT 1) AS nextTime        
FROM events AS e ) t
INNER JOIN gps AS g1 ON t.prevTime = g1.time
INNER JOIN gps AS g2 ON t.nextTime = g2.time
```

**Output:**

```
 time       lat long
-----------------------
'11:06:02'  16  16
'11:14:09'  19  19
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcfdd/10)

Comment: I have thousands of events and thousands of gps records.  Is there a way to improve speed of the last query?  May be limiting the difference between e.time and g.time to a maximum could help.  Is there another way to improve efficiency?

Comment: @RaulVerdesia You can, for a start, place surrogate PKs in your tables. Then place indices on these keys and try joining by the keys instead of `time` fields.